# How to reshape image sequence for LSTM

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to set up a RNN that will estimate the movement between two images.
 I currently have an array of 5000 grayscale images that are taken with the camera pointing toward the ground while moving. I'd like to to set up a RNN using LSTM that estimates the movement between the current image and the previous one.

Currently the images (64x64x1) are just arranged in a numpy array as such:

```
image1
image2
image3
...
```

I'm guessing I need to rearrange the array such that there are two time steps:

```
image1 image2
image2 image3
image3 image4
...
```

So how do I reshape the array such that I can use it as input for LSTM with two time steps?

Comment: `lst = lst.reshape((len(lst)+1)//2, 2)` or `lst = lst.reshape(2500, 2)`

Comment: But that would result in a list with the length of 2500, whereas I'd like an array with the length of 4999 as the images are re-occuring throughout. For example you can see in my question that image2 is present in both row no. 1 and 2, image3 is present in row no. 2 and 3, etc.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not see that :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built a little example with numpy.

```
impot numpy as np

lst = np.array(range(10))
lst
Out[56]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

lst = np.vstack((lst[:-1], lst[1:]))

# Getting the list with shape (2, len(lst)-1)
lst
Out[60]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

# Getting the list with shape (len(lst)-1, 2)
lst = lst.T
lst
Out[61]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 6],
       [6, 7],
       [7, 8],
       [8, 9]])
```

If you need to get a deep copy of the "2nd" list you can use

```
lst2 = lst[1:].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
train_images = []
for cnt, img in images:
    if cnt > 0:
        image_pairs = []
        image_pairs.append(np.array(prev_img))
        image_pairs.append(np.array(img))
        train_images.append(image_pairs)
     prev_img = img
```

I'll start thinking before I ask.

Comment: Check the example I've presented to you.